# SQL Query that returns dates that are over a year ago from the current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been trying to get a query that will take a date field from a table, and only show me the results where the date is over a year old (in respect to the current date).

I am using PHPMyAdmin for these queries. The time field's data type is 'date' (yyyy-mm-dd).

The code I have so far is

```
SELECT table1.time
FROM table1
WHERE table1.time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL -52 WEEK))
```

But the query returns every row in the table, including ones that are less than a year old.

I have tried things like `WHERE SELECT table1.time < Date_add((yy, -1, GetDate())`

But that just returns  `check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3` errors, which I don't understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use [`date_sub`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT table1.time
FROM   table1
WHERE  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) > table1.time
```

Comment: Thankyou, this was the most useful and understandable with my limited knowledge. Clear and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing `CAST(... AS DATE)` instead of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...)`; and the comparison operator should be `<`. `table1.time >` looks for dates **after** the one calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check current year and compare data of table with current year data.

```
SELECT table1.time FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(table1.time) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: That will perform very poorly on a decently sized table; the use of a function (such as YEAR) on a field (such as table1.time) necessitates a full table scan, negating any indexing benefits.